# Relationships block other content type from showing

Tags: 7, views

I have this views_slideshow and its supposed to show two content types, but shows only one. One is simple content type with image field (the one that is not getting showed) and other is commerce product type with relationships and contextual filters. So could this be something blocking this other non commerce content type from showing up? If I remove relationships for product, then it shows the Slideshow content type, but hides Products content type.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding `:title` filters and setting both to `not empty`. Also set second filter (default, not referenced) for a separate group under `OR` setting.